# Ползунок фиксированной высоты scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, input, scrollbar

Всем добрый день!

1. Мне необходимо сделать ползунок при прокрутке контента фиксированной высоты.

   [image: скрин]
2. Я смог сделать scrollbar правильной формы, а ползунок зависит от высоты элемента и количества контента в нем. Могу я как-нибудь сделать его таким, как на первой картинке.

   [image: скрин]

Вот код:

```css
.prices_scroll{
    color: #331f1f;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 500px;
    overflow-y: scroll;

}

.prices_scroll::-webkit-scrollbar{
    width: 24px;
    height: 12px;
}
.prices_scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical {
   background: #f3e1c5;
   border: 32px solid #f8b317;
   border-radius: 7px;
   height: 12px;
}  
.prices_scroll > span{
    margin-top: 30px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: #f3e1c5;
    border: 4px solid transparent;
    background-clip: content-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="prices">
  <div class="prices_scroll">
    <span>................................</span>
    <span>................................</span>
    <span>................................</span>
    <span>................................</span>
    <span>................................</span>
    <span>................................</span>
    <span>................................</span>
    <span>................................</span>
    <span>................................</span>
    <span>................................</span>
    <span>................................</span>
    <span>................................</span>
    <span>................................</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Код добавь в вопрос в виде сниппета.

Comment: Думаю тут не надо делать через стандартный скролл бар. Надо создавать блок в котором будет маленький блок он и будет ползунком.

Comment: ёще бы хорошо пример какой.

Comment: Добавил. Если не надо делать scrollbar, то, наверное, можно сделать через input/range. Только я на javascript не знаю, как мне грамотно провернуть это.

Comment: @Владислав Ким, там вообще блок скролить надо или просто ползунок двигать к нужному блоку? мне кажется что высоту стандартного скролла никак не изменить

Comment: думаю что-то вроде такого надо воссоздать http://plnkr.co/edit/qwrhqAarRXyJCEeqCJGl?p=preview

Comment: @Horchynskyi Спасибо большое! Осталось сделать его вертикальным и все будет ок!))